# Can I prevent Mac apps from pinning themselves to the dock?

Tags: dock

I have the Roblox app installed and new updates come out weekly. When I open the app for the first time after an update has been released, it updates, restarts the dock, and pins the app at the end of the dock (next to Trash). I have the "Show suggested and recent apps in dock" setting disabled.

I want to prevent it from doing so.

Comment: I would bet $$ that the Roblox app is doing that, somehow bypassing the Apple System Setting. Failing anyone with experience with Roblox here on AD you may need to seek out a discussion board/site *specifically about Roblox.*